# Elastic Beanstalk Deploy - Slow Zip

Tags: deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been using AWS Elastic Beanstalk for about 2 years now. In the past, `eb deploy` has taken more time as the project grew, but never more than 5-10 minutes.

With my latest project, I am using NextJS 13.0.3. When I use `eb deploy --verbose`, the archive creation with system zip takes 30+ minutes.

My question is: is there a reason why the ZIP is so slow? I understand the archive upload to S3 is time-heavy, but when I zip the files with the `zip` command or through the Mac Finder, it only takes 1 minute at most.

I am not including node_modules or any large images in the `eb deploy`.

Here are the first few lines of  `eb deploy ---verbose` if it helps. Thanks in advance.

```
INFO: Deploying code to [ebs environment] in region us-east-2
INFO: Getting version label from git with git-describe
Creating application version archive "app-26c2-230321_101028812043".
INFO: Found .ebignore, using system zip.
INFO: Zipping up folder at location: [folder location]
INFO:  +adding: .//
```

Comment: See this Github thread for progress on a resolution by the maintainers: https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli/issues/332

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**:  This has now been fixed in the latest version (3.20.6) `eb --version`

You can update using `pip install awsebcli --upgrade --user`

Answer (score 1):

revert back to EB CLI 3.20.3 (Python 3.11), this fixed it for me.

```
pip install awsebcli==3.20.3
```